# keras cusom fit function crashes when there is no RAM left on the server

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have overridden the `keras.fit` function and added some tensorboard utility functions to it. Everything is almost fine except the RAM usage.

when I run my code in kaggle and keep watching the RAM usage, I can see that during training, apparently my data generator which is working with `tf.data.Dataset` is accumulating the data (I guess) and does not remove the previous data in RAM.

I only include the last cell of notebook which is the training and validation process:

```
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

pattern = train_path + '*/*.jp*g'
train_ds, val_ds = generator(pattern=pattern, validation_ratio=0.2)

train_size = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(train_ds).numpy()
val_size = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(train_ds).numpy()

batch_size = 32
n_epochs = 10

val_ds = configure_for_performance(val_ds, AUTOTUNE, batch_size)

# Tensorboard utils initialization.
model_name = 'xception'
path_to_run = generate_path(join(ROOT, 'runs'), last_run=True)

tb_train_path = join(path_to_run, 'logs','train')
tb_test_path = join(path_to_run, 'logs', 'test')

train_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(tb_train_path)
test_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(tb_test_path)
train_step = test_step = 0

# Configure model, loss function and accuracy metrics.

blocks_to_train = []
lr = 1e-4
optimizer = SGD(lr=lr, decay=1e-6,momentum=0.9,nesterov=True) # Define optimizer
# optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)

model = create_model(optimizer, name=model_name, include_compile=False,blocks_to_train=blocks_to_train)

metrics = {'acc': 0.0, 'loss': 0.0, 'val_acc': 0.0, 'val_loss': 0.0, 'lr': lr}

train_loss = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy   # define loss function
val_loss = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy # define loss function

train_acc = tf.keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy # define accuracy metric
val_acc = tf.keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy # define accuracy metric

train_loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
val_loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()

train_acc_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
val_acc_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()

for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    # Iterate through the training set
    confusion = np.zeros((len(labels), len(labels)))

    train_loss_tracker.reset_states()
    train_acc_tracker.reset_states()


    print("\epoch {}/{}".format(epoch+1,n_epochs))
    progress_bar = Progbar(train_size, stateful_metrics=list(metrics.keys()))
    train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(train_size)
    train_gen = train_ds.take(train_size)
    train_gen = train_gen.map(_augment_function, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    train_gen = configure_for_performance(train_gen, AUTOTUNE, batch_size)

    for batch_idx, (x, y) in enumerate(train_gen):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = model(x, training=True)
            loss = train_loss(y, y_pred)

        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_weights)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_weights))
        train_loss_tracker.update_state(loss)

        acc = train_acc(y, y_pred) 
        train_acc_tracker.update_state(acc)
        train_step += 1
        progress_bar.update(batch_idx*batch_size, values=[('acc',train_acc_tracker.result()), 
                                       ('loss', train_loss_tracker.result())])

    with train_writer.as_default():
        tf.summary.scalar("Loss", train_loss_tracker.result(), step=epoch)
        tf.summary.scalar(
            "Accuracy", train_acc_tracker.result(), step=epoch
        )

    # reset accuracy between epochs (and for testing and test)


    """ 
    ########################################################
    #####################  Validation  #####################
    ########################################################
    """


    val_loss_tracker.reset_states()
    val_acc_tracker.reset_states()

    val_gen = val_ds.take(val_size)
    val_gen = configure_for_performance(val_gen, AUTOTUNE, batch_size)
    # train_gen = configure_for_performance(train_gen, AUTOTUNE, batch_size)

    for batch_idx, (x,y) in enumerate(val_ds):
        figure = image_grid(x.numpy(),y.numpy(), class_names=list(labels.keys()))
        y_pred = model(x, training=False)

        loss = val_loss(y, y_pred)
        val_loss_tracker.update_state(loss)

        acc = val_acc(y, y_pred) 
        val_acc_tracker.update_state(acc)
        confusion += get_confusion_matrix(y, y_pred, class_names=list(labels.keys()))

    with test_writer.as_default():
        tf.summary.scalar("Loss", val_loss_tracker.result(), step=epoch)
        tf.summary.scalar("Accuracy", val_acc_tracker.result(), step=epoch)
        tf.summary.image('Confusion Matrix',
                        plot_confusion_matrix(confusion / batch_idx,
                                            class_names=list(labels.keys())), step=epoch)
        tf.summary.image("Visualize images",plot_to_image(figure), step=epoch)

    progress_bar.update(train_size, values=[('val_acc', val_acc_tracker.result()), ('val_loss', val_loss_tracker.result())])

    # reset accuracy between epochs (and for testing and test)
```

So what is the issue with the code? What should I possibly do to stabilize the RAM usage?

Comment: full code available in https://www.kaggle.com/masouduut94/digikala-products-color-classification

Comment: I've checked your kaggle code. See my answer, and please let us know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your notebook, there are two possible issues that can cause your problem. Try with this

- put `train_gen` and `val_gen` before the `for..range(epoch)`.
- remove `.cache()` from `configure_for_performance` functions. Probabely the main cause.

### Update

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U24qC8ub0uGQiBdSZX-Yp4LGZAAt544w/view?usp=sharing) are your kaggle notebook files. I've made the above two changes. For me, when using `ds = ds.cache()`, kaggle system RAM (not VRAM), consumed 6GB within 1 epoch. But when I comment it out, it reduced to 2.1GB. Here is some more info regarding [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance#caching).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but using your tip in my code did not make much different.

Comment: I ran your notebook. It consumes less system memory using the above approach. Using `cache()` is the cause of an over-consuming memory issue. What difference did you observe using this tips?

Comment: Check this link, Its my repo. https://github.com/masouduut94/digikala-color-classification.  you can write an issue here and share the code with me. thank you

Comment: I found out that the problem is with this line `tf.summary.image("Visualize images",plot_to_image(figure), step=epoch)`.  apparently plots keep the RAM busy.  The `tf.data` is not causing the problem.

Comment: I see. Usually, we like to use `tf. summary` inside the custom training loop if we need it. So, if it causes as such you described then it's kind of a bug or something. As you know in it's a common practice in another framework like `pytorch` or `pytorch-lighting`, we do such ploting inside the training loop to viz on the tesnorboard.

Comment: As far as I can say, it should not be the cause. You should double-check it. And if you get it's cause such problem in custom training loop wrt `sequence` or `tf.data` input pipeline, then please ask a new question with those details. And probably raise an issue on `tf` github.

Comment: There is another issue with the code which really drives me crazy, The training loss sounds logical (like 0.9) but the validation loss is so high (in epoch 5 it gets around 800) which is really weird and it linearly increases. what should I change in the code probably?

Comment: Can't say exactly. But I would suggest you not use the custom training loop. Use `.fit`, as you should know, in that case, you can get built-in callbacks method like reducle_learing_rate, learning_rate_sched, etc to control various metrics i.e. `val_loss`. ec.

Comment: If in any case you really want to control the `train_step` function, then override the `.fit` method.

Comment: Otherwise, if you insist want to stick with your current training loop, then you have to also write by yourself methods like `reducle_learing_rate`, `learning_rate_sched` to penalize `val_loss` in your case.